# JWT Interceptor Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I'd like to make people who hold the JWT can access all APIs but people can only access on EXCLUDE PATH now. what should I set up for that?

This is my WebConfig.

```
private static final String[] EXCLUDE_PATHS = {
            "/api/user/**"
    };
    

public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
        registry.addInterceptor(jwtInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/**")
                .excludePathPatterns(EXCLUDE_PATHS);
```

This is my interceptor.

```
public class JwtInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static final String HEADER_AUTH = "Authorization";

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        final String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_AUTH);

        if(token !=null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)){
            return true;
        }else{
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
```

this is my validateToken fn

```
public boolean validateToken(String jwtToken) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(jwtToken);
            return !claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

this is my doFilter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) request);

        if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {

            Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

This is my security Config.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(jwtTokenProvider),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


    }
```

Am I missing something? I add the Security Config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use WebSecurity instead of interceptors.

Something like this for configuring which paths can be accessed and which cannot

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

This [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-jwt-authorization-and-authentication-in-spring/) should help you well.

Comment: Hi. I added my WebSecurityConfig. is that wrong?